# Continuity of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $f(z)=xy+iy$ is everywhere continuous but is not analytic.

We have $\displaystyle w=f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and $\displaystyle z=x+iy$.

Do I just say that as both u and v here are polynomials, so there are continuous everywhere??

How to show that some function is continuous everywhere?

Second part is to check the C-R equations, which are not satisfied, so the function is not analytic.

Anything to add/substract here?

Comment: How to show that some function is continuous everywhere? What if f(z) was a little more complicated?

Comment: You would have to show that $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are continuous everywhere, using multivariable calculus usual methods.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. But I am a noob at this .. trying to read and solve problems from a textbook .. so I can't say I understand what you meant.. but hoping that it might make more sense to me later.. :)

Comment: Have you taken multivariable calculus? Have you deal with things like $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (3,2)} x^2y + \sin(xy) \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^4}$$ before? Have you heard of line integrals? If no, then you are probably not ready for taking a complex variable course.

Comment: I hope this doesn't come across as rude, but it's a statement of a fact.

Comment: What I know is we test for continuity at a point.. how to check for continuity everywhere ?? .. The examples you mentioned are continuity tests at a point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15555/discussion-between-square-one-and-fantini).

Comment: You test at each point. To do that you fix an arbitrary point and show that it is continuous there. Since the point was arbitrary, the conclusion is valid for all points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observing that they are each polynomials is enough to see that the function is continuous in each variable separately but not necessarily that it is continuous. (You probably saw examples in Calc III where a function was not continuous at the origin even though it was continuous in each variable separately at the origin. That is, where $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x,0)$ and $\lim_{y \to 0} f(0,y)$ both exist but $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ does not exist.)

An easier way is to write $f(z)=y(x+i)$, then it is a product of two polynomials, each of which are continuous, therefore it is continuous.

Comment: Examples of functions you are alluring to are rational functions, not polynomial functions. Polynomial functions are really continuous and suffice to point it out.

Comment: How to show that some function is continuous everywhere? What if f(z) was a little more complicated?

Comment: For a typical complex variable course, simple observations like being a polynomial or similar are generally enough. An analytic argument would need to use the $\varepsilon$,$\delta$ definition that you'd find in a real analysis book, or else prove that limits of the function exist and equal the value of the function at each point.